# Override Textbox Properties In VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

It is possible to override textbox properties like selectionstart property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectionStart` property is not marked as `virtual`, so you can not override it. Other properties that are `virtual` or `overridable` can be overridden.

Comment: ok but when assign text to textbox that time selection start property is 0. how to solve this problem

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can by creating your own textbox class, such as

```
Class MyTextBox
    Inherits TextBox

    Public Shadows Property SelectionStart As Integer
        Get
            '   Get Code
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Integer)
            '   Set code 
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own custom control that inherits from the textbox control and override whatever events you need to.
[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h62478z%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is some guidance from MSDN.